# density function of U when Y has a beta distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that Y has a beta distribution with parameters a and b. Find the density function of U = 1 - Y.

I know how to do then when they give the density function of Y, but i'm confused here.

Thanks!

Comment: You know the integral expression for the CDF, don't you? Take also into account that the integral of your PDF over the whole real line should be equal to 1.

Comment: I guess i don't know the integral expression for the CDF. Is the integral expression the same for all beta distributions?

Comment: ya i don't get how to go about doing this. Am I supposed to use the density function of y equal to: y^(a-1)(1-y)^(b-1)/B(a,b) where B(a,b) = integral of y^(a-1)(1-y)^(b-1)dy with respect to y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for the density function of a beta$(\alpha,\beta)$ random variable, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution.

Now, if $Y$ is beta distributed, then it takes values in $(0,1)$. Hence, $U = 1 - Y$ also takes values in $(0,1)$.
In order to find the density of $U$, it is useful to find first its distribution function, and then differentiate it.
The distribution function of $U$ at $x \in (0,1)$ is the tail distribution function of $Y$ at $1-x$. By taking complement, you get the distribution function of $U$ expressed in terms of that of $Y$. Differentiating it, you get the density of $U$ expressed in terms of that of $Y$. You should find out that $U$ and $Y$ are very closely related.

Comment: So the limits of my integrals are -1 to 0. And i'm integrating the density functions of a beta distribution (that big complicated thing) with respect to y. Then to find the answer im taking the integral with respect to u. Right?

Comment: or the limits should be from 0 to u+1 rather? i think...

Comment: If you follow my guidance above, you should see that the integral of the density function plays no role here; indeed, you should express the density of $U$ in terms of that of $Y$ (as I explained), and then substitute into the expression for the density of $Y$ (which you know). It may be helpful to note here that ${\rm B}(a,b) = {\rm B}(b,a)$